# Hi guys. I have built ROS from source on my PI 2 but I am unable to import libraries

Tags: ros, std-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not being able to import even the basic libraries such as with `from std_msgs import Strings`in my python scripts.
Please help me fix this issue.

EDIT

This is my CMakeLists.txt  :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ior_internet)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
)

catkin_package
(
 ##INCLUDE_DIRS include
 ##LIBRARIES ior_internet
 ##CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
 ##DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

And this is my package.xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
<name>ior_internet</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>The ior_internet package</description>

<license>TODO</license>

<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
<run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
<run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>

</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229304/hi-guys.-i-have-built-ros-from-source-on-my-pi-2-but-i-am-unable-to-import-libraries./) by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-17**:
This is not enough information

However, this could be a dependency issue, if you installed everything correctly.
Please post your `CMakeLists.txt` as well as the `package.xml` (and also remove any comments, please).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. It was because I was not doing `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the beginning of my scripts. It seems it is important. Now my scripts work as expected.

---

Originally posted by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) with karma: 47 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duh, my bad. Could have seen this before.

The import statements for messages within `rospy` should look like this:

```
from std_msgs.msg import String
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-18**:
I tried that but i still get the same error. I cant import anything. Not even `import rospy`

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-18**:
Have you sourced `/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`? Or the respective workspace?

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-21**:
Yes, I did that.